# android:clickable does not work

Tags: android

I have a `RelativeLayout` and want to disable any touching events for the lower layer, however, putting `android:clickable="true"` on the upper level does not do the trick. Could you please take a look:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <Button
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="lower layer button" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:clickable="true">
             <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="upper layer button"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can still click both buttons. What may be wrong with this piece of code?

**Edited to make the question clearer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found the answer:

My second layer did not intercept all touching events because it was smaller than the  first layer. So even though android:clickable="true" is needed this is not enough. The bottom layer should not be larger than the upper layer. Making second RelativeLayout size inheritable fixed the issue:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="lower layer button" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:clickable="true">
             <Button
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="upper layer button"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are clickable by default. If you want a button to not be clickable, you have to explicitly set the property to false:

```
<!-- this will be clickable -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test test test"
    android:clickable="true" />

<!-- this will not be clickable -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false" />
```